# Meteor: How to delete two documents from two collections with a single click in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, events, meteor

Some "news documents" (one collection) might have an image included (another collection I'm using `cfs:standard-packages`and 
`cfs:filesystem`for handling files.)

This is a news document in the Mongo Database:

```
{
    "_id" : "75d5nZGitsLvo5APM",
    "title" : "News with Image",
    "description" : "This news entry has an image",
    "type" : "news",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-01-31T15:46:01.334Z"),
    "coverImageId" : "js5k88PuPeKJwRqcq"
}
```

This is a image document:

```
{
    "_id" : "js5k88PuPeKJwRqcq",
    "original" : {
        "name" : "amir_rahbaran.jpg",
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2014-02-14T14:56:36.000Z"),
        "size" : 41614,
        "type" : "image/jpeg"
    },
    "uploadedAt" : ISODate("2016-01-31T15:45:58.060Z"),
    "copies" : {
        "images" : {
            "name" : "amir_rahbaran.jpg",
            "type" : "image/jpeg",
            "size" : 41614,
            "key" : "images-js5k88PuPeKJwRqcq-amir_rahbaran.jpg",
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-01-31T15:45:58.000Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-01-31T15:45:58.000Z")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem: An admin might want to delete a news entry. Currently, one the news document get's deleted. So the images are kept in the database. As you can see, the `coverImageId` in the news document and the `_id` in the image document are **identical**.

My template.js:

```
Template.adminNewsEventsList.events({
    'click #js-delete-ne': function (evt,template) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var deleteConfirmation = confirm('Really delete this entry?');
        if (deleteConfirmation) {
            Images.remove({_id: "coverImageId"});
            NewsEvents.remove(this._id);
        };
    }
});
```

My template.html:

```
<template name="adminNewsEventsList">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            {{#each newsEventsData}}
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item">
                <a title="Edit" id="js-edit-ne" href="{{pathFor route='adminNewsEventsEdit'}}">{{title}}</a>
                <!-- edit button -->
                <a title="Edit" id="js-edit-ne" class="btn btn-primary" href="{{pathFor route='adminNewsEventsEdit'}}"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>
                <!-- delete button -->
                <a title="Edit" id="js-delete-ne" class="btn btn-danger" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the moment I wanted to hit the submit button, the solution popped into my head. I still share it, as it might be useful for others.

The line: `Images.remove({_id: "coverImageId"})` has to be changed to:

`Images.remove({_id: this.coverImageId})`

Hope someone will find it beneficial.

Any improvements still appreciated.